# Unable to bypass SSL certificate verification failure

Tags: r, ssl, keras, rstudio, cifar100

Attempting to run the following line of code:

```
data <- dataset_cifar100("fine")
```

results in:

> Error: Exception: URL fetch failure on [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz): None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1131)

I've tried:

```
set_config( config( ssl.verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

and various other similar commands to no avail.

I've also tried manually downloading and loading the dataset from the binaries, but I'm running into trouble there as well, and I'd much prefer to do it the easier way.

Comment: When I use `curl -vI https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz` on the CLI or `curlGetHeaders("https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz",verify = TRUE)` in R I do see a valid certificate.

Comment: Regardless, I'm still encountering this error. Did you try loading the dataset?

Comment: Yes, and executing `keras::dataset_cifar100("fine")` results in a successful download of that file. Which does not really surprise me given the TLS cert I am seeing.

Comment: This might be an issue w/ conda. Are you keras through conda? If so, what version of reticulate are you on? Does installing the development version of reticulate fix the error?